# How to properly connect to Fuseki Triple store

Tags: c#, rdf, fuseki, dotnetrdf

I currently work on a project that requires me to insert and query data to a graph hosted on a Apache Jena Fuseki triple store. I am however unable to connect to said store.
So far i tried two different methods:

### Method 1

```
 store = new FusekiStore("triplestore.project.customer.de", "Datasetname", "User", "fusekiPassword");
_model = store.GetModel(new Uri("https://triplestore.project.customer.de/Datasetname/"));
```

when using this method the `store` is created an when debugging shows `store.IsReady = true`. `_model` is also created, however upon inspection i see `_model.IsEmpty` throws `System.UriFormatException`. I do get the same exception when calling `_model.CreateResource<T>(new Uri("https://triplestore.project.customer.de/Datasetname/" + id))`

### Method 2

```
var cred = new NetworkCredential("User", fusekiPassword);
store = StoreFactory.CreateSparqlEndpointStore(new Uri("https://triplestore.project.customer.de/Datasetname/data"), null, cred);
_model = store.GetModel(new Uri("https://triplestore.project.customer.de/Datasetname/"));
```

Once again the `store` is created, however `store.IsReady` throws a `System.NotImplementedException`.
Ignoring that, i continue trying to create an resouce: `_model.CreateResource<T>(new Uri("https://triplestore.project.customer.de/Datasetname/" + id))`. This time i get a

```
VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException: "A HTTP Error occurred while trying to make the SPARQL Query, see inner exception for details

InnerException  {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
```

### Question

Which is the correct method, to connect to a Fuseki Store using Trinity RDF and how is it done?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: isn't it more like `const string connectionString = "provider=fuseki;host=http://localhost:3030;uid=admin;pw=test;dataset=ds";
            
            var store = StoreFactory.CreateStore(connectionString);` - and you have to adapt the connection string to your setup?

Comment: There are tests in the Github repo, maybe those help? https://github.com/semiodesk/trinity-rdf/blob/develop/tests/Trinity.Tests.Fuseki/ModelTest.cs

Comment: Thanks alot, i have missed those. First try seems promising.

Comment: Ok, so after testing the solution proposed by @UninformedUser , I encounterd another problem. When calling `store.InitializeFromConfiguration();` the following exception is thrown: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."` This makes sense since òntologies.config` is an XML file. Looking into the decompiled InitializeFromConfiguration()` i can`t find why it is trying to open the file with an JSON Parse. Any Ideas?